# How to improve a SCN-based query performance?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

In Oracle database there is a [pseudocolumn which's called `ora_rowscn`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm). If it's retrieved it shows the SCN of the most recent change to the row (as it's said in the documentation).

Also there's an option `rowdependencies` of `CREATE TABLE` which switches on storage of SCN for each row instead of a whole data block (which is default).

So, I'm using values of this column for indicating which rows were updated and are needed to be uploaded to another database.

Let's consider this example:

1. There's a table `T1` in schema `S1` which contains several millions of records (full scan on the table is not affordable for regular queries).

   ```
   CREATE TABLE T1 {
     A INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     B VARCHAR2(100),
     C DATE
   }
   /
   ```
2. There're schemas `S2, S3, S4, S5..` and in each of them there's table `T2`.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE T2 {
     A INTEGER
   }
   /
   ```
3. There's only one row in `T2`, but value of `T2.A` can be different in different schemas.

So, I need to retrieve in each schema `(S2, S3, S4...)` all rows from `S1.T1` which have value of `ora_rowscn` greater than `S*.T2.A` (then I use this data block). 
After gettting these rows I rewrite value of `S*.T2.A` with the current system SCN (`dbms_flashback.get_system_change_number`).

The following queries for any schema is right here:

Query 1:

```
SELECT * FROM S1.T1 WHERE ora_rowscn > (SELECT A FROM T2);
```

Query 2 (it's performed when I finished work with dataset returned by the previous query):

```
UPDATE T2 SET A = dbms_flashback.get_system_change_number;
```

The problem is that performance of query 1 is unacceptable (full scan on the table `S1.T1`) and the column `ora_rowscn` can't be indexed.

The question: **What could be the ways to improve the performance of the query 1?**

Comment: Queries 1 and 2 are performed let's say every minute.

Comment: why don't you just query the table using flashback  `select * from S1.T1 as of timestamp (sysdate - 1)` ??

Comment: maybe because it's totally a different thing? I don't need data of the past, I need all the updated data since my last query

Comment: Hopefully your real version is taking into account SCN increments between when you start query 1 and get the current SCN from query 2? Otherwise you'll have a hole in the data from each run, however fast you make it. (With SCN or a `last_updated` field). I guess the obvious way to deal with that is to store two values in `T2` and query between them.

Comment: Well, yeah, you're right about this. That's why I actually save the value of current SCN in a variable before perfroming query 1, and after it's finished, I write saved value into `T2`, here omitted this fact in order to simplify the question

Comment: I suppose the SCN would be indexable if it was a real column maintained with a trigger, but you might as well use a timestamp (just as the rest of the world does, frankly).

Comment: There are the same issues with locks I described in a comment to Vincent Malgrat's answer with user-defined SCN. It doesn't work efficiently on a heavy-loaded system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't index `ora_rowscn`. Consequently the best plan for query 1 is a `FULL TABLE SCAN`.

Since this is not acceptable, you will have to use another marker, for example a `last_updated` `date` column. This column is indexable but you'll have to update it. You can automatize this update with a small light-weight trigger.

Performance of query 1 against an indexed column will be dependent upon the number of rows retrieved.

Comment: I've already considered so-told 'user-defined SCN', when you use user-defined `sequence` and `integer` column which contains the next value of the `sequence` each time a row is updated, but I came across some collisions with holes in datasets (some simultaniously updated rows were lost, don't remember now why).. An option to use `date` or `timestamp` instead is a nice idea which worth being tried. Can't say if it will always work right now, but will hope.

Comment: Are there any other ideas? My eyes were directed into materialized views and indexes on them, but not sure it'll work.. Talking about this solution - I came across here some severe issues with locks - since the `last_updated` column is frequently changed, I need to renew statistics about the index on it with, possibly, rebuilding the index itself, but it's hardly possible, due to the fact that frequent updates prevent index from being rebuilt (resource is busy).

Comment: @ZZa materialized view log would log all changes to the source table, and it is basically a table itself, so I guess you could index and query it. However usage of it for your manual processing is tricky and unsupported/undocumented.

Comment: @zza Another idea here would be to set up AQ. You have N consumer of data, each would receive the updates/inserts since the last time it emptied its queue.

Comment: @zza I don't understand the issue about locks here: the N schemas that need the updates/deletes don't update the main table, they are only *readers* and thus can't block other process and can't be blocked.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat the problem is not about the N schemas - they only read data and don't modify it, there're no locks, but there are two concurrently working processes - the trigger which updates value `last_updated` column really frequently and the job which regathers statistics for table `T1` and rebuilds index on `last_updated` (without this job the index is almost useless - data of the column changes so fast that statistics and index expire really fast) - and they lock each other's work (`resource is busy` exception).

Comment: @VincentMalgrat what is AQ? could you post explain this option as an answer?

Comment: Don't rebuild indexes while the table is updated. In most cases don't rebuild indexes, it's pointless -- let the index grow to its stable desirable size. AQ is [Oracle Streams Advanced Queuing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/cmntopc.htm#sthref2104). I don't have a lot of experience with AQ but I'll see if I can write an answer.

Comment: It isn't clear to me how I could use a "small light-weight trigger" to update something from the ORA_ROWSCN--after all, I cannot retreive an ORA_ROWSCN from trigger.  Assuming I need this column to track the commit order and not the insert order, a trigger won't help me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

All you care about is, which rows have been inserted or updated since the last time you ran the upload.

Why not add a flag to the table that marks each row as "dirty" - i.e. a before insert trigger would set it to 'X' and a before update trigger would set it to 'X'.

Then, write your upload process to query the table for any row where the flag is NOT NULL, then set the flag to NULL when it succeeds. Note that this means that new rows that get inserted/updated *while the upload is in progress* will still get marked correctly, and will be picked up the next time the upload runs.

If the number of rows inserted/updated compared with the total rows in the table is a very small ratio, an index on the flag will be useful, because NULL flags will not be stored in the index (i.e. the index will usually be small.

EDIT:

An equivalent solution for situations where multiple schemas need to be updated is to have a separate table which will hold the IDs of rows that have changed. The table should have a flag for each target schema. When all the flags have been set to NULL, delete the row from the table.

Comment: This way is not correct in general, it works only if you have ONE schema where you need to know the changes, because after using a dataset you reset the _dirty_ flag and it's not available for other schemas anymore. I'll need then as many markers as many schemas I have. But it's not acceptable, they're added dynamically and there're about three hundreds right now and just imagine what it means to add three hundred columns with indexes on them on a table with several millions rows (at least in size terms).

Comment: Fine - but just because you think it's impractical for your situation doesn't mean it is not "correct". It works, I've tried it.

Comment: If you select a row with a non-null flag, then it gets changed, do you not lose that change if you subsequently set the flag back to null? It seems that unless you can guarantee no changes between selecting the row and resetting the flag then data changes will be lost?

Comment: Good point David - we'd need to protect against clobbering a concurrent change, e.g. add a VERSION_ID column as well which is increased on each update; our upload process would then only update the flag to NULL as long as VERSION_ID is the same as when queried, e.g. `UPDATE mytable SET flag = NULL WHERE version_id = :version_id_as_queried`.